# Why can’t I use df.loc() within the drop() method?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I’m just getting started on pandas and I was trying to delete a sequence of rows.

In my data frame, the index is the province names.

Since `df.loc[‘NL’:’QC’]` returns a list of rows, I thought I would feed that as an input to my drop function to specify which rows I want deleted, but it doesn’t work.
Can someone help me understand why? Thank you.

This is what I wrote

```
df.drop(df.loc[‘NL’:’QC’])
```

It threw an error that said could not find ‘province’ , ‘province_name’ etc on axis.
These are the names of my columns.

I know that by default the `drop()` will have `axis =0` , so I’m not sure why it’s parsing through columns? Or why it “can’t” find it.

If I change `axis = 1`, it works and all my columns disappear.
Just my indices remain from NL to QC and nothing else.

Apologies if I’m not explaining it the best, I’m just starting out and may not be using the best words to describe my problem.
Appreciate the help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pandas `drop` function gets an input

> "Index or column labels to drop. A tuple will be used as a single label and not treated as a list-like."

Therefore you should pass the indices and not the rows -

`df.drop(df.loc['NL':'QC'].index)`

See more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

Comment: I see, thank you so much for explaining that! 
Would it be possible to expand upon why then the code worked when I changed the axis = 1?

Answer (score 0):

[`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) requires a list of the indices, not a slice. You should pass the [`index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.index.html):

```
df.drop(df.loc['NL':'QC'].index)
```

*NB. In your case you were passing the full DataFrame.*